# Required error while selecting an option

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm using Laravel 5.4 when i want to publish a post i get required error even with selected item.

this is my store part of post controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validate the date
    $this->validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
            'category_id' => 'required|integer',
            'body'  => 'required',
            'tags' => 'sometimes',
            'featured_image' => 'sometimes|image'
        ));

    // store in the database
    $post = new Post;

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->slug = $request->slug;
    $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $post->body = $request->body;
    $post->tags_id = $request->tags_id;

    //Save featured image
    if($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {
        $image = $request->file('featured_image');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('uploads/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);

        $post->image = $filename;
    }

    $post->save();

    $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

    Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully save!');

    // redirect to anther page
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

and this is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'posts.store', 'data-parsley-validate' => '', 'files' => true)) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <!-- <div class="panel"> -->


                            <!-- title -->
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> {{ Form::label('title', 'Title:') }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            {{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-lg', 'required' => '', 'maxlenght' => '255')) }}
                            </div>

                            <!-- slug -->
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <i class="fa fa-link"></i> {{ Form::label('slug', 'Slug:') }} <small>hello_world. Use(_) between words.</small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            {{ Form::text('slug', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'minlenght' => '5','maxlenght' => '255')) }}
                            </div>


                            <!-- Category -->
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category:') }}
                            </div>
                            <select class="form-control" name="category">
                                @foreach($categories as $category)
                                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>

                            <!-- body -->
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <i class="fa fa-book"></i> {{ Form::label('body', 'Post Body:') }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            {{ Form::textarea('body', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'id' => 'bodytext')) }}
                            </div>

                            <!-- Tags -->
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <i class="fa fa-tags"></i> {{ Form::label('tags', 'Tags:') }}
                            </div>
                            <select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">
                                @foreach($tags as $tag)
                                <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="panel panel panel-bordered panel-info">

                            <!-- image -->
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-image"></i> {{ Form::label('featured_image', 'Upload Featured Image') }}</h3>
                                <div class="panel-actions">
                                    <a class="panel-action" data-toggle="panel-collapse" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                {{ Form::File('featured_image') }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- button -->
                        <div class="panel panel panel-bordered panel-warning">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i> Actions</h3>
                                <div class="panel-actions">
                                    <a class="panel-action" data-toggle="panel-collapse" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                {{ Form::submit('Publish it', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'margin-top: 20px;')) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I don't know where is exactly the problem, any idea?

Comment: Are you getting the error from the `category` field?

Comment: You need to decide between `category` and `category_id`.

Comment: Your field is called `category` but you're retrieving the value from `category_id`. Correct one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you have name `category` for the input field. But in the controller you are checking for `category_id`.

**Suggestion:**

Why not use *LaravelCollective HTML package* for `select` field as well?

```
{!! Form::select(
        'category_id',
        $category_list,
        null,
        ['class' => 'form-control']
   ) !!}
```

In the controller in `create` function.

```
$category_list = Category::lists('id', 'name')->all();
```

Pass this variable to the view.

Comment: thanks the problem was name of form field. 
I am using LaravelCollective  just gave it position with bootstrap html's.

Comment: Well, the credit goes to @fubar (in comments) for that.